# Mismatched input 'end of line without line continuation' expecting ')'

Tags: conditional-statements

I am trying to add a long and short condition to plot long or short signal based on the following conditions:

```
longCond = ta.crossover(s9ema, s13ema) and (s9ema > s50ema) and (s50ema > s200ema) and price is  > s13ema)
shortCond = ta.crossunder(s9ema, s13ema) and (s9ema < s50ema) and (s50ema < s200ema) and (price( < s13ema)
```

Here is the code but I am getting an error (Mismatched input 'end of line without line continuation' expecting ')' in lines 14 and 15

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Rockets&Torpedos", overlay=true)

s9ema = ta.ema(close, 9)
s13ema = ta.ema(close, 13)
s50ema = ta.ema(close, 50)
s200ema = ta.ema(close, 200)

plot(s9ema, title="Ema 9", color=color.rgb(114, 255, 82), linewidth = 1, transp=0)
plot(s13ema, title="Ema 13", color=color.rgb(212, 0, 0), linewidth = 1, transp=0)
plot(s50ema, title="Ema 50", color=color.rgb(255, 0, 187), linewidth = 2, transp=0)
plot(s200ema, title="Ema 200", color=color.gray, linewidth = 2, transp=0)

**longCond = ta.crossover(s9ema, s13ema) and (s9ema > s50ema) and (s50ema > s200ema) and (input.price(const.float > s13ema)
shortCond = ta.crossunder(s9ema, s13ema) and (s9ema < s50ema) and (s50ema < s200ema) and (input.price(const.float < s13ema)
**
plotshape(series=longCond, title="Long", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, text="LONG", size=size.small)
plotshape(series=shortCond, title="Short", style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, text="SHORT", size=size.small)
```

Everything works fine if I remove the last and conditions

```
(input.price(const.float > s13ema) or (input.price(const.float < s13ema) from lines 14 and 15

longCond = ta.crossover(s9ema, s13ema) and (s9ema > s50ema) and (s50ema > s200ema) and *(input.price(const.float > s13ema)*
shortCond = ta.crossunder(s9ema, s13ema) and (s9ema < s50ema) and (s50ema < s200ema) and *(input.price(const.float < s13ema)*
```